# Sorting through two loop results with provided offset and limit

Tags: c++

I'm currently attempting to return results that are obtained inside two for loops with two optional paramaters of `limit` and an `offset`. The result will also return `more` with an unisigned int with the remaining entries.

Intialized data prior to loop:

```
uint32_t search_results = 0;
uint32_t search_limit = p.limit;
bool contSearch = false;
uint32_t search_offset = p.offset;
uint32_t returnCount = 0; //more
```

First loop:

```
for (size_t knpos = 0; knpos < names_rows_result.rows.size(); knpos++)
```

Here is the first set of logic that allows for the offset and limit to work after the first loop and prior to the 2nd:

```
            if (!contSearch) {
                if (search_limit >= requests_rows_result.rows.size() || (p.limit - p.offset) == 0 || p.limit == 0) {
                    search_limit = requests_rows_result.rows.size();
                    contSearch = true;
                } else {
                    search_limit = (p.limit - p.offset);
                }
                search_results = (requests_rows_result.rows.size() - search_limit);
            } else {
                search_limit = requests_rows_result.rows.size();
                search_results += (requests_rows_result.rows.size() - search_limit);
            }
```

Inside the second loop:

```
if( search_offset < requests_rows_result.rows.size() ){
   for (size_t pos = 0 + search_offset; pos < search_limit; pos++) {
        //GATHERS DATA
        result.requests.push_back(DATA);
        returnCount++;
   }
}
```

This seems to work for the first loop through but when it goes to the next entry for `knpos`, I'm having a little trouble returning only the data requested.

Comment: `search_limit = requests_rows_result.rows.size();
search_results += (requests_rows_result.rows.size() - search_limit);` -- That last line doesn't change `search_results`, since `request_rows_result.rows.size() - search_limit` is 0.  I think you need to take a step back and revisit all of that logic, since it seems to me to be overly wordy and complex.  The lines I pointed out are an example.

Comment: The output it suppose to be 0 for that case. Search results is the amount left/`more`

Comment: So why are you writing a line of unnecessary code?  The more unnecessary lines of code, the harder the code becomes to understand, and the easier it is for a mistake to be made.

Comment: How is it unnecessary? The offset and limit are optional params. Won't work without that line.

Comment: `search_limit = requests_rows_result.rows.size();
search_results += 0;` -- You are adding 0 here.  What is the effect of adding 0 to a number?

Comment: Its not always 0. If limit is 1 and offset is set to 0, you'll have 1.

Comment: In that `else` block, it is always 0.  Are you reading the code carefully?

Comment: If limit is 1 and offset is set to 0, you'll have 1.

Comment: One more time:  `search_limit = requests_rows_result.rows.size();
search_results += (requests_rows_result.rows.size() - search_limit);` -- Do you not see that `search_limit` is set to whatever `requests_rows_reult.rows.size()` is?  OK, now do you see the very next line?  What does it all boil down to?  Unless the laws of addition and subtraction have changed, when you subtract the same quantities from each other, you get 0.  If you need proof, put a breakpoint at that line, and see this for yourself -- the logic should have been clear to you in that `else` block, but obviously it isn't.